# Cannot infer type for type parameter `I` declared on the function `tuple` when parsing with nom

Tags: rust, nom

I am trying to use [`nom`](https://docs.rs/nom/5.1.2/nom/)'s [`tuple`](https://docs.rs/nom/5.1.2/nom/sequence/fn.tuple.html) function. The documentation presents the following example:

```rust
use nom::sequence::tuple;
use nom::character::complete::{alpha1, digit1};
let parser = tuple((alpha1, digit1, alpha1));
```

When I try it out, I get a compile error:

```
    error[E0283]: type annotations needed
   --> src/main.rs:20:18
    |
20  |     let parser = tuple((alpha1, digit1, alpha1));
    |         ------   ^^^^^ cannot infer type for type parameter `I` declared on the function `tuple`
    |         |
    |         consider giving `parser` a type
    |
```

If I wanted to add a type to the variable, what would it be? I know it has to be some variation of `FnMut`, but I am unsure how it would work exactly.

**Cargo.toml**

```
[dependencies]
nom = ">=5.0"
```

Comment: If you actually copy the full example from the documentation, including the `assert_eq!()` calls, it compiles fine. The lines using the parser give the type inference the additional hints it needs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Type inference requires enough information to actually infer the type. You can either provide the required information by copying the full example from the documentation, including the two `assert_eq!()` statements:

```
use nom::sequence::tuple;
use nom::character::complete::{alpha1, digit1};
let mut parser = tuple((alpha1, digit1, alpha1));

assert_eq!(parser("abc123def"), Ok(("", ("abc", "123", "def"))));
assert_eq!(parser("123def"), Err(Err::Error(("123def", ErrorKind::Alpha))));
```

The additional calls inform the compiler about the argument and return type of the function returned by `tuple()`, which in turn gives the compiler enough information to infer all type parameters of the `tuple()` call.

Alternatively, you can explicitly pass type parameters to the `tuple()` function. Here is the minimal amount of information you need to provide for Rust to be able to infer all types:

```
let _parser = tuple::<&str, _, (_, _), _>((alpha1, digit1, alpha1));
```

Note that the details of how type inference works in Rust are not part of the language specification, and may change in future versions of Rust. While Rust has quite strong backwards compatibility guarantees, you sometimes may need to add some type annotations to your code when upgrading to a newer version.

Comment: Thank you, that makes a lot of sense.